# Поисковые роботы и meta keywords

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Сайтами я занимался давно, тогда нужно было вводить ключевые слова чтобы страницы индексировались роботами. Да и после этого всё не так просто было с индексацией (ну по крайней мере мне так казалось). Но вот прошло вроде как лет 5-7. Хотелось бы узнать, нужно ли сейчас делать что-то особенное с сайтом, после готового дизайна и наполнения его контентом?

В гугле даже не знаю как вбить. Все описывают создание сайта либо SEO и как то размыто, в общем по поводу этих ключевых слов. Кто-то пишет "надо", кто-то пишет что уже их игнорируют и роботы анализируют контент. В общем я немного сбит с толку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta keywords *не нужны*.

Все современные поисковые движки игнорируют этот тег. Наоборот, от использования meta keywords один вред, потому что вы палите конкурентам слова, по которым вы оптимизируете сайт. Некоторые поисковики могут использовать ключевые слова, если вы включите туда абсолютно уникальные слова, в ранжировании ключевые слова при этом всё равно не участвуют. Некоторые поисковики используют ключевые слова для проверки на спам.

Удалите и больше никогда про них не вспоминайте.

Что касается мета-информации, то за последние "лет 5-7" появились и активно развиваются микроформаты. Например, можно указать на странице адрес так, чтобы его можно было алгоритмически легко распарсить. Есть микроформаты для статей, расписаний, товаров, рейтингов и т.п. Использование микроформатов может привести к тому, что результат будет красиво отображён на странице поиска. Можно добавить на страницу информацию о том, как её отобразить при "расшаривании" и т.п.

В общем, смотрите в сторону размещения на странице полезной информации (текст, микроформаты), а не бесполезной (ключевые слова).